# OutOfMemory from reading files in Android

Tags: android, memory

```
openGeoid = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.geoid));
        geoidIndex = (int)Math.round(latOff * 1441 + longOff);

        for(int c = 0;c <= geoidIndex;c++){     
            geoidStr = openGeoid.next();
            if(c == geoidIndex){
                geoid = Double.parseDouble(geoidStr);
            }   
        }   

        openGeoid.close();
```

This is my code, and apparantly something is causing an OutOfMemory error. I am trying to read from a file which has about 1 million values. I am suspecting that reading too much at once is causing this error. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: What is the structure of R.raw.geoid file?

Comment: txt file. The first few lines goes   13.606   13.606   13.606   13.606   13.606   13.606   13.606   13.606  @vokilam

Comment: Explain your goal. Does all values have same format?